# ionic 3 Runtime error : t.resolve is not a function

Tags: ionic3

I get this error when i run ionic serve.

[image]

Here are the devdependencies for reference.

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.20",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi @Aditya Were you able to find a fix for this ?

Comment: Actually it was an issue with the version of an npm package , after changing the version this error didn't occur.